# Добавление в админку формы, не связанной ни с одной моделью

Tags: django, django-admin

Возможно использовать в админке форму, которая не связана ни с одной моделью? Только для сбора информации, которая уже будет использоваться в определенной модели. Развернутый вопрос с картинками ниже.

Имеется абстрактная модель свойства предмета CommonProperty, которая зависит от объекта Element:

```css
class Element(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Element'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Elements'

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(verbose_name="Symbol", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class CommonProperty(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Property element'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Property elements'
        abstract = True

    TYPE = (
        (THERMAL, 'thermal'),
        (PHYSICAL, 'physical'),
        (CLASSIFICATION, 'classification'),

    )

    NOTATION = (
        (DECIMAL, 'decimal'),
        (SCIENTIFIC, 'scientific'),
        (STRING, 'string'),
    )

    element = ForeignKey(Element)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Property title", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(verbose_name="Property type", max_length=50, choices=TYPE)
    notation = models.CharField(verbose_name="Property notation", max_length=50, choices=NOTATION)
```

CommonProperty содержит выбор типа (как значение этого свойства будет записано - десятичным числом, инженерной записью или просто строкой). В зависимости от выбранного типа используется соответвующая модель - наследник CommonProperty

```css
class PropertyDecimalNotation(CommonProperty):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Decimal Notation'

    value = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Value", blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(verbose_name="Unit", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class PropertyScientificNotation(CommonProperty):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Scientific Notation'

    significand = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Significand", blank=True, null=True)
    base = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Base", blank=True, null=True)
    exponent = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Exponent", blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(verbose_name="Unit", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class PropertyStringNotation(CommonProperty):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Property string notatio'

    value = models.CharField(verbose_name="Value", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(verbose_name="Unit", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

**И собственно вопрос**

Можно ли в админке организовать следующую логику.

1. Изначально в админке присутствует форма выбора типа и формы записи свойства. Где мы можем указать заголовок будущего свойства, выбрать группу и формат записи. Это промежуточная форма для абстрактой модели CommonProperty

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. В зависимости от выбора формата записи (десятичное число, инженерный вид или строка), после сохранения объекта (или нажатия на кнопку Add property) мы получаем новую форму, где уже детально заполняем свойства элемента

   На рисунке в качестве примера выбрал инженерный формат записи числа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно ли организовать форму по полям абстрактной модели? и уже данные этой формы использовать при созлании необходимых записейв БД? дайте, пожалуйста, советы

Answer (score 1):

Стандартными средствами админки джанго работать через свои формы нельзя. Админка - это высокоуровневый интерфейс для работы с базой данных.

Но можно перепиливать саму админку, если уж ваша задача не попала в 90% решаемых. Хотя это задача не тривиальная. Есть, например, возможность [переопределять шаблоны](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/contrib/admin/index.html#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template)

На самом деле, как я понимаю ваш уровень, то будет проще намного сделать отдельную страничку с нужной формой, не трогая административный интерфейс.

Comment: да, уже думал об отдельной странице добавления. про уровень вы правы, простую кастомизацию и подмену шаблонов выполнить могу, а эта задача вызвала у меня большие затруднения

Comment: Спасибо за лайки, но нет смысла их накидывать в таких количествах, так как система таки "набросы" удаляет. в конце суток.

Comment: буду знать. надо все-таки как-то интерес поощерять. но могу дизлайкать)